# iPhone/iPad: 2d character animation, as a MP4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a few character animations I want to add to my app. For example, let's say "dog wags tail" just for sake of example.

I'm wondering if a .mp4 (or other video file) can be used for this, or is it better to just roll through a sequence of .pngs ? (Can a .mp4 support transparency, and also occupy a subset of the screen?). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use CoreAnimation to accomplish this.

Here is decent tutorial on one technique using sprites:

http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2011/01/cag1/